# JSON VALUE AS QUERY STRING

Tags: javascript, json, drupal-7, geoip, maxmind

I'm using Maxmind.Com's GeoIP2 (Omni) Webservice on my Drupal 7 website to pull geographic data based on my visitor's IP.

I am able to get a JSON document by using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.0/geoip2.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var onSuccess = function(location){
    console.log(
        "Lookup successful:\n\n"
        + JSON.stringify(location.city.names.en, undefined, 4)
    );
};

var onError = function(error){
    alert(
        "Error:\n\n"
        + JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 4)
    );
};

geoip2.omni(onSuccess, onError);

</script>
```

One of the returned values is the visitor's city name. How can I use the returned value as part of a query string?

For example, if `'city.names.en' = 'Detroit'`, how could I use "Detroit" as a key to retrieve data (e.g. Local phone number) from another document, table, etc?

The end goal is to dynamically insert a "local" phone number into the "contact us" section based on the visitor's location.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'll format a query string like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/route?parameterName=value
```

For your example it may look like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/phoneNumbers/phoneNumber?city=Detroit
```

Comment: Thanks Jake, this is a helpful reply, but what if I my goal is to send the above request to Maxmind.com to determine the user's city, then use that city name to populate the phone number field when the page loads? I guess I'm having trouble "chaining" (if that's an appropriate term) these queries together, since the city name is unknown until I receive the response from maxmind. In other words, how do I write a script that will pull/insert "phone#" as soon as "cityname" is known?

Comment: In other-other words, how can I say, when the first JSON response is received, 'load' [link](http://mydomain.com/phoneNumbers/phoneNumber?city="TBD cityname")

Comment: That sounds like an instance where you'd want to look at using promises. You can wait for a result and then, if successful, handle the response.  jQuery has some built-in functionality for doing that.   http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/  && https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Am I on the right track with this?:   <code> <script>

var onSuccess = function(location){
 console.log(
        "Lookup successful:\n\n"
        + JSON.stringify(location.city.names.en, undefined, 4)
    )
.done(function(location)
      $.get("http://mydomain.com/phoneNumbers/phoneNumber?city=" + location.city.names.en);
};


var onError = function(error){
    console.log(
        "Error:\n\n"
        + JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 4)
    );
};

 

geoip2.omni(onSuccess, onError);

</script> </code>

Answer (score 0):

There can be two approach to achieve what you want to do.

- Load the contact information after getting the city name using ajax. Here's an example:

`<span id="contact"></span>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        geoip2.omni(function(data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "your/url/to/contact/getter/service",
                data: {
                    city : data.city.names.en
                },
                success: function(contact) {
                    // update your contact information
                    $("#contact").text(contact);
                }
            }
        }, function(data) {
            debugger;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Obviously, you need a resource that you can request to provide the contact information given the city name.

- Create a contact information map and use it to get the contact information for a City without having to send a request again.

`<span id="contact"></span>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var contactMap = {
        NewYork : "123123",
        London : "9797987"
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        geoip2.omni(function(data) {
            // update your contact information
            $("#contact").text(contactMap[data.city.names.en]);
        }, function(data) {
            debugger;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I was able to get option two to work. I will also play around with the first option when I have some time. I cannot thank you enough. I have spent the last month trying to figure this out and I am beyond happy right now. Thank you.